# Vector of templated objects

Tags: c++, templates, object, vector

I am working on a project that uses templated objects as a vector argument. I must strictly use objects and any primitive types. I'm working on a smaller example to help me grasp the bigger picture.

So far, here is what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Thing {
    public: 

        Thing(T type) {
            memVar = type;
        }

        T getMemVar() {
            return memVar;
        }

    private:
      T memVar;
};

class U {
    public:

        U(int i) {
            j = i;
        }

        int getJ () {
            return j;
        }

    private:

        int j;

};

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    vector < Thing <U> > v;

    v.push_back(); // idk how to add new elements to this vector.
                   // I've tried: v.push_back(Thing <U> i(U)),
                   //             v.push_back(U obj(4)), etc etc...

    return 0;
}
```

I don't know how to add elements to this vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By example

```
v.push_back(Thing<U>(4));
```

If you can compile C++11 or newer, even simpler

```
v.emplace_back(4)
```

But, in both cases, you have to modify the constructor of `Thing` as follows

```
Thing(T type) : memVar(type) {
}
```

or add a default constructor in `U`

```
U () {
}
```

because your `Thing` constructor try to initialize `memVar` without arguments and next to copy `type` in `memVar`

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for your insight on this. I've spent 3 days trying to figure this out. I can't express how thankful I am.

Comment: @TheoHandy - You're wellcome; anser improved in case you can compile C++11 or newer.